# UWP: How do you make a Border a click through shield?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have situation where I want an overlay control to block UI interactions on a Page for everything that is behind a border.  I have tried setting Border.ManipulationMode to False.  I have set IsTapEnabled, IsRightTapEnabled, IsDoubleTapEnabled, and IsHitTestVisible to False.

I also tried subscribing to the Tapped and PointerEntered events, and setting the args Handled property to true. After all of this I can still click on Buttons through the border, and invoke their commands.  Below are a few screenshots for context:

[Page with no overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwMJw.png)

[Page now has what should be an overlay that blocks controls behind it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvsZ5.png)

[A button capturing PointerOver that shouldn't be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arotL.png)

Here is the UserControl xaml that becomes the overaly on the Page:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PocMvvmToolkitApp.Dialogs.DialogShell"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid x:Name="overlayGrid"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!--dialogShield is the Border that I want to prevent click through on-->
    <Border x:Name="dialogShield"
            Background="#AAFFFFFF"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"
            ManipulationMode="None"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
            IsHoldingEnabled="False"
            IsRightTapEnabled="False"
            IsTapEnabled="False"/>
    <Border x:Name="dialogBorder"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1" />
</Grid>
```

Attempting to handle the events:

```
        public DialogShell()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.allDialogs = new List<ExtendedContentDialog>();
        this.visibleDialogs = new List<ExtendedContentDialog>();

        ////Doesn't work
        this.dialogShield.PointerEntered += this.OnModalShieldPointerEntered;
        this.dialogShield.Tapped += this.OnModalShieldTapped;
    }

    private void OnModalShieldTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ////Doesn't block click through
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnModalShieldPointerEntered(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

On the Page.xaml.cs here is where I add or remove the DialogShell control to the parent Grid on the page:

```
        private void OnDialogStackChanged(Args.DialogStackChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Context)
        {
            case Args.DialogStackChangedContext.Showing:
                if (this.dialogShell == null)
                {
                    this.dialogShell = new DialogShell();
                    this.dialogShell.ShowDialog(args.Dialog);

                    this.rootGrid.Children.Add(this.dialogShell);
                    Grid.SetColumnSpan(this.dialogShell, 2);
                }


                break;
            case Args.DialogStackChangedContext.Closing:
                if (this.dialogShell != null)
                {
                    this.dialogShell.RemoveDialog(args.Dialog);
                    if (this.dialogShell.AllDialogs.Count == 0)
                    {
                        this.rootGrid.Children.Remove(this.dialogShell);
                        this.dialogShell = null;
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

Any help with this Border situation would be appreciated.  Before someone recommends using ContentDialog, please don't, I have my reasons for this setup.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior just with the code you shared. Please try to reproduce this behavior in a blank UWP app and share the code that could reproduce this behavior.  Maybe you could try to set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the button that you want to disable when the usercontrol is shown.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Roy.  I have pushed this code to a github repo:

https://github.com/cjfarr/PocMvvmToolkitApp

I did try a simpler scenario with two buttons and a border on a single page.  I got the desired effect there.  I also wasn't sure if adding the control at runtime had an impact, but it doesn't.  In the repo I switched to adding the DialogShell in the xaml of the MainPage, and then toggled Visiblity on the DialogShell as needed.  I can still click through the border shield in that scenario too.  Thank you for any insight on what the difference might be.

Comment: Could you please reproduce this issue in a simple blank project, [mcve] which is better for troubleshooting the issue?